# Updated to Angular 9 and raw-loader no longer working

Tags: angular, webpack

Just updated to ng 9 and getting the following error when attempting to build:

> Cannot find module '!raw-loader!./help/vdpviewsHelp.html'

We've been using raw-loader to load some html files as string and haven't had issues until updating. Has anyone else run into this or can advise on how to get Web-Pack to load html templates as strings again?

Thanks

Comment: what was the app version before updated ?

Comment: It was ng 8@latest

Comment: can you share your `extra-webpack-config.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In angular 9 `raw-loader` was updated to `4.0.0` version.
I don't know the exact root of your problem, but maybe one of following tips will work for you:

1) `import css from '!!raw-loader!./file.txt';` // Adding `!!` to a request will disable all loaders specified in the configuration
- change call for the `vdpviewsHelp.html` with `!!` as in documentation for `raw-laoder@4.0.0`
2) Basically you can install your own version of `raw-loader` and it will be used.
Add it to your `package.json` `devDependencies` section:
`"raw-loader": "0.5.1"`
- it is version that worked for me, when I faced this issue.

Comment: `npm i --save-dev raw-loader` and `const styles = require('../[path]/styles.css').default` worked for me in Angular 14.  Seems every time I update the Angular version I need to change the way I import these css files.